# cannot connect ktor project to postgres - Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, ktor

I am new to ktor, postgres. I am trying to connect ktor to postgres and I get the following error

`Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc.postgresql:notes_db?user=postgres&password=<masked>`

DatabaseFactory in ktor project. Application.kt calls the init method to create the table in the database

```
object DatabaseFactory {

    fun init() {
        Database.connect(hikari())

        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(UserTable)
        }
    }

    fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.driverClassName = System.getenv("JDBC_DRIVER") // 1
        config.jdbcUrl = System.getenv("DATABASE_URL") // 2
        config.maximumPoolSize = 3
        config.isAutoCommit = false
        config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        config.validate()

        return HikariDataSource(config)
    }

    suspend fun <T> dbQuery(block: () -> T): T =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            transaction { block() }
        }
}
```

attached a picture of configuration and environment variables

[image]

Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong here please.

thank you so much in advance
R

Comment: It must be `jdbc:postgresql` not `jdbc.postgresql`

Comment: cannot thank you enough, it was a stupid mistake I agree, but thank you so much..

Comment: it works absolutely fine now